# Angularjs select all checkboxes do not persist when paginating

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-table, servicenow, selectall

Our team is building a table in ServiceNow and making edits to the out-of-the-box Data Table widget so that a user can select all rows on a given page.  The following is our current code (HTML and controller):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive" ng-if="data.list.length">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-if="options.show_checkboxes">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="c.checkAll()" ng-model="selectAll">
        </th> 
        <th ng-repeat="field in data.fields_array track by $index" class="text-nowrap" ng-click="setOrderBy(field)"
         scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-sort="{{field == data.o ? (data.d == 'asc'? 'ascending': 'descending') : 'none'}}">
          <div class="th-title" title="${Sort by} {{field == data.o ? (data.d == 'asc' ?  '${Descending}': '${Ascending}') : '${Ascending}'}}" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="{{data.column_labels[field]}}">{{data.column_labels[field]}}</div>
          <i class="fa" ng-if="field == data.o" ng-class="{'asc': 'fa-chevron-up', 'desc': 'fa-chevron-down'}[data.d]"></i>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in data.list track by item.sys_id">
        <td ng-if="options.show_checkboxes">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-checked="selectAll || item.selected">
        </td> 
        <td role="cell" class="pointer sp-list-cell" ng-class="{selected: item.selected}" ng-click="go(item.targetTable, item)" ng-repeat="field in ::data.fields_array" data-field="{{::field}}" data-th="{{::data.column_labels[field]}}"><span ng-if="$first" aria-label="${Open record}: {{::item[field].display_value}}" role="link" tabindex="0">{{::item[field].display_value | limitTo : item[field].limit}}{{::item[field].display_value.length > item[field].limit ? '...' : ''}}</span><span ng-if="!$first">{{::item[field].display_value | limitTo : item[field].limit}}{{::item[field].display_value.length > item[field].limit ? '...' : ''}}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

c.checkAll = function() {
  var allChecked = false;
  for(var i = 0; i<$scope.data.list.length; i++){
    if($scope.data.list[i].selected ==true){
      allChecked = true;
    }else{
       allChecked = false;
    }
  }

  if(allChecked ==true){
    for(i = 0; i<$scope.data.list.length; i++){
      $scope.data.list[i].selected = false;
    }
  }else{
    for(i = 0; i<$scope.data.list.length; i++){
      $scope.data.list[i].selected = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code allows us to select each row individually and it allows for us to select all rows on a given page.  The issue is if the table contains 5 pages, each page containing 5 rows...if a user selects  any number of rows, then navigates to another page, all those selected rows are "forgotten".  Is there a way to select rows and have them persist with pagination?

Here are some screenshots of the scenario:
First we select all rows on page load
[image: select all rows on page load]

Then we navigate to the second page
[image]

Then when we navigate back to the first page, all of the rows we selected are "forgotten", but the select all checkbox is still checked

[image]

Comment: Including the paging code would help. I'm guessing here but it sounds like that changing the page is fetching a new $scope.data.list which would cause you to lose any previous selections.

Comment: thanks @GabrielGates, any suggestions on how to keep the scope?

Comment: You could keep track of the selected items in a separate javascript object. Then post fetch of the list, loop over the list and set the item.selected property.

Comment: Gabriel ist probably right. Servicenow replaces the whole data object on rowChange. You would need to make an object (data.selected), filled with sysIds of selected records, persist it in server script (data.selected = input.selected) and on any action (like approve()) you need to work with data.selected instead of the servicenow OOTB object.Quite the task and I'm not surprised SNOW didn't implement it themselves...